# x509 serial number - hex or decimal

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, openssl, x.509

When I run the openssl command

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in certname
```

on different certs, on some I get a serial number which looks like this.

```
Serial Number: 256 (0x100)
```

On others, I get one which looks like this

```
Serial Number:
        41:d7:4b:97:ae:4f:3e:d2:5b:85:06:99:51:a7:b0:62
```

The certificates I create using openssl command line always look like the first one. 
What do I need to do to create a cert using openssl command line where the serial number looks like the second?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just a representation choice for presentation purposes. If it's short enough, it will be displayed both in decimal and in hexadecimal. You just need to use a longer serial number for it to appear in the second format (`0x100` would be equivalent to `01:00`).

The length threshold to switch to the second representation [seems to be `size(long)`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/asn1/t_x509.c#L138)  (usually 4 bytes).

Comment: stupid openssl has no notion of consistency